# Group isomorphism of intersections

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

In the syllabus for my course on group theory, there is the following theorem which is proven: "If $H \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ is a subgroup, then $H \cong \mathbb{Z}^k$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$".

I understand most of the proof, but there's a simple line that is intuitive, yet doesn't mathematically make sense to me.

In the proof, which is done by induction, the following homomorphism is defined
$$\pi: \mathbb{Z}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}: \pi(m_1,...,m_{n+1}) = m_{n+1}.$$
The kernel of the map is considered, which are all vectors of the form $(m_1,...,m_n,0)$.

Then the syllabus reads "Since $H \subset \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ is a subgroup, also $H \cap \text{ Ker}(\pi) \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ is a subgroup."

That is the part that confuses me. Both $H$ and Ker$(\pi)$ are subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$. I realize that Ker$(\pi) \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$, but I don't see how it follows that $H \cap \text{ Ker}(\pi)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, rather than $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$. As far as I know, even though the last element of each vector in the intersection will always be equal to 0, that does not mean that the vectors are of dimension $n$ rather than $n+1$.

Can someone explain to me why the intersection can be considered a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

You actually already said the answer. $\mathrm{Ker}(\pi)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$ and $H \cap \mathrm{Ker}(\pi)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Ker}(\pi)$, and so we can consider it as a subgrouop of $\mathbb Z^n$.

Comment: Okay that does make sense. What I got mainly confused by is the notation that $H\cap\text{ Ker}(\pi)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, How does isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ of one half of the intersection imply that the full intersection is a subgroup (and hence subset) of $\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: @surfer1311 If $G$ is a group and $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $H\subset K$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $K$.  Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$, $K = \ker{\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

if you take  an element $x$ of the intersection then it belong to both $H$ and $ker(\pi)$ and because $ker (\pi)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^{n}$ then the $x$ belongs to it
finally the intersection is a subgroup.